# What should come to your mind when you see a Serialized Java Object

Tags: java, serialization

I've got some code, written by someone who is no more with our company. He has used Serialization (implements Serializable) in quite a few places in the code and I think it is unnecessary.

What precautions should I be taking care of, before removing those serializations from the code?

**EDIT - Added below**

1) Our code is not accessed via a network. No streaming needed. No Servlets too.
2) No Object to byte array conversion happens anywhere
3) It is just a standalone application running in a single JVM
4) It just reads a file and puts the data in database. The database may be remote.
5) Doesn't have any RMI/Corba Components
6) No known parent of these classes are Serializable

Any other case to be taken care of?

Comment: Well, why do you think they are unnecessary?

Comment: if ever that class is field of any class being written to a stream

Comment: I think this question could be phrased in a awy that is more appropriate to the site.

Comment: You need a much stronger reason than 'I think' to mess with working code. *Much* stronger. If you were working for me you wouldn't get to first base with what you've presented so far.

Answer (score 2):

I would be tempted to leave them as they are relatively harmless if not used.  Many classes in the JDK are `Serializable` but it is not a problem.

If you have checked these classes are never `Serializable` you can remove this.  If this is easy to test reliably, you could do so.  Otherwise I wouldn't take the risk, just don't do it in the future. (Make classes `Serializable` which are not)

Answer (score 2):

> What precautions should I be taking care of, before removing those serializations from the code.

Make sure that you have a good set of unit tests and system tests available ... and use version control.

You could also search your codebase for code that uses the ObjectStream classes, but the usage could be hidden in libraries and framework code.

I agree with Peter.  Removing `implements Seralizable` is unlikely to achieve anything worthwhile.  (At least ... not from your manager's perspective.)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that there are libraries that need classes to be `Serializable`.

As it does no harm I would leave it in the code.